# Find the volume bounded by the paraboloid $x^2+y^2=az$, the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2ay$ and the plane $z=0$

Tags: multiple-integral

Find the volume bounded by the paraboloid $x^2+y^2=az$, the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2ay$ and the plane $z=0$

**My work**

Changing to cylindrical coordinates

For Paraboloid

$$x^2+y^2=az\;\;\;\implies r^2=az\;\;\;\implies z=\frac{r^2}{a}$$

For the cylinder

$$x^2+y^2=2ay\;\;\;\implies r=2a \sin \theta$$

Since this volume lies only in first two quadrants $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$

Volume=$\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{r=0}^{2a\sin \theta}\int_{z=0}^{r^2/a}r\ dr\ d\theta \ dz$

Comment: Well, $y\in[0..2a], x\in[-\sqrt{2ay-y^2}..\sqrt{2ay-y^2}], z\in[0..(x^2+y^2)/a]$ but a change of variables might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Using cylinder coordinate is the best way to solve this problem : 
$$\left\{(r\cos\theta ,r\sin\theta +a ,z)\mid \theta \in [0,2\pi], r\in[0,a], z\in \left[0,\frac{2r^2+2ar\sin \theta+a^2}{a}\right]\right\}.$$

Comment: Yes, it does look much easier. But what would be the limits in cartesian coords?

Comment: @user467745 : Something as $y\in [0,2a]$, $x\in [-\sqrt{2a-(y-1)^2},\sqrt{2a-(y-1)^2}]$ and $z\in [0, \frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{a}]$.

Comment: Just to cross check-the answer would be $\pi a^3$, right?

Comment: @user467745: I'm not a computer ;-)

Comment: Did I imply that? I am sorry. Thanks for your time

Comment: @user467745: no, don't worry :) I just don't know the solution, and I'm lazy to compute the volume. But If the technique is good, then so the result should be :-)

Comment: The volume is outside of the paraboloid, but in the cylinder. So it is bounded by the paraboloid and the cylinder. So shouldn't the limits be $\theta \in [0,\pi], r \in [0,2a\ sin \theta], z \in [0,\frac{r^2}{a}]$. What do you think?

Comment: @user467745: Indeed, I made a mistakes, but your parametrisation is not correct. I edited my post.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the limits set out by you. I have made some edits of my own in the _my work_ section of the question itself. If you have the time, could you look at it? What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @user467745: The best is to make a draw... You can put your solution, and I'll check what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to re-order your integration.  You can also exploit the symmetry of the region of integration about the $ \ yz- $ plane by integrating over $ \theta $ from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ .  Thus,

$$ V \ = \ 2 \ \int_{ 0}^{ \pi / 2}\int_{0}^{2a\sin \theta}\int_{0}^{r^2/a} \ \ \ dz \  \ r \ dr \ \  d\theta \ \ = \ \ 2 \ \int_{ 0}^{ \pi / 2}\int_{0}^{2a\sin \theta}  \ \  \frac{r^2}{a}  ·  r \ dr \ \  d\theta $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{2}{a} \ \int_{ 0}^{ \pi / 2}  \ \  \frac{1}{4} \ (2a \sin \theta)^4  \ \  d\theta \ \ = \ \ \frac{2·2^4·a^4}{4a} \ \int_{ 0}^{ \pi / 2}   \sin^4 \theta   \ \  d\theta \ \ = \ \ 8a^3 \ · \ \frac{3 \pi}{16} $$

$$  = \ \ \frac{3 \pi}{2}a^3 \ \ ,  $$

the last definite integral being of a kind $ \left( \ \int_{ 0}^{ \pi / 2}   \sin^n \theta   \ \  d\theta \  =  \ \int_{ 0}^{ \pi / 2}   \cos^n \theta   \ \  d\theta \ \right) $ for which a formula to evaluate it is available.